# Why is the output 5 when sum doesn't return anything?

Tags: c, function, printf, output

the sum function doesn't have any return type specified also it doesn't have any return statement still the output on a turbo c compiler is 5. Can anyone explain why, I guess it's because the printf function prints 5 characters and maybe returns the number of characters printed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

sum()
{
    printf("hello");
}

void main()
{

    int k;
    k = sum();

    clrscr();
    printf("%d",k);
    getch();

}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Turbo C++ is a history. Do not repeat it.

Comment: though it's undefined it's asked in quizzes and tests.

Comment: Goes to show the worth of those "quizzes and tests".

Comment: The more interesting question would be "why not?"

Comment: Or even better: "Why doesn't your compiler jump into your face and bite if you don't return anything in `sum`. Or when you use `void main()`"

Comment: @Michi - `sum` is not a function with a `void` return type. The duplicate fits perfectly

Comment: @Michi - The OP doesn't have a `void` returning function (slight of an oxymoron of a term). Their code should not compile in strict ISO C. But it does, probably because the compiler still implementes the "implicit int" rule. `sum` is an `int` returning function without a return statement. For the purposes of reasoning about this UB, `int` or `char` is immaterial.